# SQL Statistical Analsis

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am planning a "statistics" page for a university project where lots of factoids will be displayed based on data from my Access database.

The statistics will be displayed in text format like so:

*23%* of **drinkers** enjoyed **Life of Pi** whilst only *15%* of **non-drinkers** like it.

*65%* of teachers have read **Othello by William Shakespeare** whilst only *40%* of **policemen** have read it.

[I have **bolded** the values I know how to retrieve in an SQL statement, and have *italicized* the percentages which I don't know how to compute]

User details include Boolean values such as smoker:yes/no or drinker:yes/no as well as the user's profession (there will be a limited number of professions listed in a combobox). These are all stored in a table called 'userprofiles'

I have a separate table called 'booklist' that stores the names,authors,title etc of books as well as a table called 'booklikejunction' where the likes for each book are recorded as well as the user's current `User.Identity.Name`

What would my SQL statement look like? And how would I display the results of my query in the format I have outlined above?

Comment: have you tried anything?  this is a JOIN with an aggregate function and GROUP BY

Comment: @Randy I have various other pages in my website that are all complete, and this is the "cherry on the cake" so to speak. Unfortunately I cannot experiment at the minute as I only have my Mac with me and not my Windows pc. I was just trying to get an understanding of how I would go about doing this - thanks for your direction - gets me started at least. I will update this page with my code as I progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hint (using ms-access SQL syntax):

```
select sum(iif([field1]='drinker',1,0)) / count([field1])
from [tbl_questions]
where ...
```

Not the cleanest way to do it, but it works

Comment: Would you suggest I use a label to load the data into: [label(percentage)] of [label(profession)] have read [label(name of book)] or do you have a better way of displaying my statistics?

Comment: Use the label you prefer. I sugest you keep field labels simple, and use more "detailed" captions on your reports